# Laravel 5 and Entrust. How to create subscription model based on roles and assignment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Let's say i've three categories of people. I would like to separate them with the following.

```
Admin->SuperAdmin
Staff->Can be Manager
Member->Subscriber
```

I have installed the Github repo for Entrust. 
Just need a bit guidance, how to tackle this for my project.

Comment: i hope laravel authorization will help you http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Comment: yes, familiarize yourself with laravel authorization first. laravel uses a single table (and a single model of course) to handle users. and to achieve what you want, you could refer to [laravel single table inheritance](http://www.colorfultyping.com/single-table-inheritance-in-laravel-4/). it is laravel 4, but hopefully works on 5. alternatively, rather than works on your own, [GitHub Single Table Inheritance](https://github.com/Nanigans/single-table-inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should follow the instructions in repo **[Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#configuration)** that cover (Installation / Configuration / Usage) phases with following plan :

- Installation
- Configuration

  - User relation to roles
  - Models

    - Role
    - Permission
    - User
    - Soft Deleting
- Usage

  - Concepts

    - Checking for Roles & Permissions
    - User ability
  - Blade templates
  - Middleware
  - Short syntax route filter
  - Route filter

Also you can watch the **[Laravel 5.1 (Windows) - 060 - installer le package zizaco/entrust (autentication complexe)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WSq5-vwc8M)** it will take you from scratch to the implementaion .

**NOTE :** You may want to take a look at **[Laravel 5.1 authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization)** first.

Comment: I got it all sorted out. Thanks @zakaria-acharki